# How to call function within a div or custom tag attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to call a function in the customized tag

```
<t-dropdown name='Name' callback="testFn">
    </t-dropdown>

<script>
  function testFn(value){
    console.log(value);
  }
</script>
```

In js

```
var callbackFn = document.getElementsByTagName("t-dropdown")[0].getAttribute("callback");
var abc = 10;
callbackFn(abc);
```

Please suggest how will approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var callbackFn = window[document.getElementsByTagName("t-dropdown")[0].getAttribute("callback")];
var abc = 12;

if(typeof callbackFn === 'function') {
    callbackFn(abc);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<t-dropdown name='Name' callback="testFn">
    </t-dropdown>
<script>
  function testFn(value){
    console.log(value);
  }
</script>
```